# Configuration of Angular environment

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, docker, visual-studio

I'm trying to configure the Angular environment for the existing project developed by someone else. When I'm trying to install all dependencies, I'm getting below error:

[image]

I've found, that this error is the cause of the missing data in one of my grid. Could you help me to solve the issue?

[image]

Also, I'm getting another issue:
[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the log messages, source code, and other details required in plain text rather than image files?  It's not at all clear what these pictures are showing or what code one might need to run to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This error is because of a mismatch in the dependencies of your project. You have `@angular/core@9` and `@ngx-translate/core@13` in your `package.json`. These are not compatible since `@ngx-translate/core@13` requires a minimum angular version of `@angular/core@10`. You have two options:

- You can either update angular to a version greater than `@angular/core@9` or downgrade `@ngx-translate/core` to a lower version that is compatible with `@angular/core@9`.
- You can install the dependencies with `npm install --force` or `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`. However this is not recomended since it will basically ignore the dependencies requirements and install everything as it is.

You can read more about node peer deps [here](https://nodejs.org/es/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/).