# I can't run a built Angular project - ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I'm following a tutorial of Angular and I wanted to run a project built by the instructor.
This is what I do to run it (I found these steps in the 'how-to-use' file)

> ##### How to use
>
> Run "npm install" inside this project folder to install all
> dependencies.
>
> Make sure you use the latest version of the CLI (upgrade guide below)
>
> Run "ng serve" to see the app in action (try "npm start" in case "ng
> serve" fails).
>
> Feel free to compare it with your project code to spot any errors you
> might have.
>
> ##### How to upgrade the CLI
>
> Run the below commands - only use "sudo" on Mac/ Linux.
>
> ```
> sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
> npm cache clean --force
> sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
> ```

Upgrading the CLI works just fine, but when I move to the `npm install` command I get these errors:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: my-first-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   dev jasmine-core@"~3.6.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.8" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0
npm ERR! node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!   dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/t/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/t/.npm/_logs/2022-09-28T12_08_00_585Z-debug-0.log
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-first-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "^11.0.5",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.9",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

this is Angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-first-app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/my-first-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-first-app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-first-app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-first-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "my-first-app-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "my-first-app:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "my-first-app"
}
```

Comment: The answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73821902/configuration-of-angular-environment/73822332#73822332 may help you.

Comment: @alexortizl The seconde option doesn't work ``npm install --legacy-peer-deps`` after runing it I tried ng serve but I got an error : Error: Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server' builder's node package.

Comment: @alexortizl the first option, which is upgrading Angular version, is a little bit complicated for a beginner like me. so I'm still trying.

Answer (score 1):

I had kind of the same issue following the "Tutorial: Your First App"

https://angular.io/tutorial/first-app/

I ran the npm command appending --force
... as the error prompt suggests.

```
npm install --force
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is an issue with your dependencies. One of your packages requires a `jasmine-core` version greater than or equal to `3.8` and your `package.json` is installing version `3.6`. You just need to update it in `package.json` Here is a copy of your `package.json` with this change, note the version in `jasmine-core`. With this `package.json` you just need to run `npm install` and then `npm start`.

```
{
  "name": "my-first-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "^11.0.5",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.9",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Every time I try this my laptop restarts, I have MacOs 10.13.6.